# Extending GitInfoContributor to add properties?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Before I discovered Spring Boot's Info Actuator had almost everything I wanted to publish, I made a few meta endpoints to ensure that I could access build and Git information that would help when trying to validate things like:

- "Is the right version deployed?"
- "Who built this?"
- "When was it built?"
- "Which git commit is this based on?"

After doing that, I did get around to discovering the Info actuator and that it answers almost all of those questions for me, but there are a few things from the Git information that I'd like to add -- mostly the commit message and the dirty flag.

I looked at the output if I turn on full git metadata with:

```
management.info.git.mode=full
```

But ... that adds a lot more information, most of which I don't care about, so it's more than I really want.

What I'd like to do is take the GitInfoContributor and extend/replace it, but I'm not totally sure how to do that. It's easy to add my own contributor, but if I add my own contributor and call builder.withDetails("git"), like this:

```
package ca.cpp.api.submitapi.config

import org.springframework.boot.actuate.info.Info
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.info.InfoContributor
import org.springframework.boot.info.GitProperties
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
class CustomGitInfoContributor(private val properties: GitProperties): InfoContributor {
    override fun contribute(builder: Info.Builder?) {
        builder?.withDetail("git",mapOf("dirty" to properties.get("dirty"))
    }
}
```

This replaces the whole set of git properties, and in the meantime, I think the core GitInfoContributor will still be there, still be providing information that I'm throwing away.

Is there a reasonable way to add only the elements I want, either with my own contributor that can merge its information with the info already under "git" or by somehow extending/replacing the existing GitInfoContributor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simplest way to add new element under "git" part is extending GitInfoContributor

kotlin:

```
@Component
class CustomGitInfoContributor @Autowired
constructor(properties: GitProperties) : GitInfoContributor(properties) {

    override fun contribute(builder: Info.Builder) {
        val map = generateContent()
        map["dirty"] = properties.get("dirty")
        builder.withDetail("git", map)
    }
}
```

java:

```
@Component
public class CustomGitInfoContributor extends GitInfoContributor {

  @Autowired
  public CustomGitInfoContributor(GitProperties properties) {
    super(properties);
  }

  @Override
  public void contribute(Info.Builder builder) {
    Map<String, Object> map = generateContent();
    map.put("dirty", getProperties().get("dirty"));
    builder.withDetail("git", map);
  }
}
```

This code will add dirty part after default git info e.g. `{"git":{"commit":{"time":"2018-11-03T15:22:51Z","id":"caa2ef0"},"branch":"master","dirty":"true"}}`

In case you do not want to generate the default git info part simple remove `generateContent()` call.

Comment: Works like a charm -- I added some more properties, but your examples were spot on for the concept, and I appreciate the effort to include Kotlin and Java examples. ;)